# Core Web API as Virtual Directory in IIS

Tags: iis, webapi

I have a Asp.net Core web API and i want to host deploy it under existing WebSite rather than creating a new one.How to do that , anyone please suggest

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#sub-applications

Answer (score 2):

The virtual directory is a directory name (also referred to as path) that you specify in Internet Information Services (IIS) 7 and map to a physical directory on a local or remote server. The virtual directory name becomes part of the application's URL, and users can request the URL from a browser to access content in the physical directory. But if you want to deploy asp.net core web api under existing WebSite, you need to add application instead of virtual directory under the website. about how to host an ASP.NET Core app as a sub-app under another ASP.NET Core app you can refer to this link: [Sub-applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#sub-applications)